# Continuous functions $P$ and $Q$ on $[0,1]$ such that $y(t)=\sin(t^2)$ is a solution for $y''+P(t)y'+Q(t)y=0~~\text{on}~ (0,1]$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does there exists continuous functions $P$ and $Q$ on $[0,1]$ such that $y(t)=\sin(t^2)$ is a solution for the second order differential equation $$y''+P(t)y'+Q(t)y=0~~\text{on}~ (0,1]$$ ?

Here I can't apply the Wronskian condition for linearly independent solutions of the equation since domain is $(0,1]$. Furthermore $P$ and $Q$ should be continuous on $[0,1]$.

Comment: You can start with computing the first two derivatives of $y(t) = \sin(t^2)$ and plug these expressions into the ODE. Then see what you might choose for P and Q.

Comment: P and Q should be continuous on [0,1]

Comment: There is only one possible choice (did you try to find it?), and $P$ is undefined at $t=0$. So you can either relax your auxiliary condition and exclude $t=0$, or else the answer would be no, such functions do not exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\begin{split}
y(t) &= \sin{(t^2)}\\
y'(t)&=2t \cos{(t^2)}\\
y''(t) &= 2\left(\cos{(t^2)}-2t^2\sin{(t^2)} \right) =  2\cos{(t^2)}-4t^2\sin{(t^2)}
\end{split}
$$

So your equation becomes
$$
\left[2\cos{(t^2)}-4t^2\sin{(t^2)}\right]+ P(t) \left[2t \cos{(t^2)}\right] + Q(t)\left[\sin{(t^2)}\right] = 0 \tag 1
$$
Let $f(t)$ be the LHS of the equation, so

$$
f(t) = y''(t) +P(t)y'(t) +Q(t)y(t)
$$
We know that $ f(t)=0$ for every $t \in (0,1]$.  If we suppose that $P$ and $Q$ are continous, then $f$ is continous (why?) hence $f(0)$ should be equal to $0$. But
$$
\lim_{t\to 0^+} f(t) = 2
$$
So $P$ and $Q$ cannot be continous in $t=0$, since $\lim\limits_{t \to 0^+} f(t) \neq f(0)$.

We can rewrite equation $(1)$ :
$$
2\cos{(t^2)}\Big[tP(t)+1\Big] + \sin{(t^2)} \Big[Q(t)-4t^2 \Big] = 0
$$
Hence $P(t)= - \frac{1}{t}$ and $Q(t)=4t^2$ satisfy equation $(1)$.
Note that $P$ is not continous on $t=0$ (actually it's not definied there).

**Exercise**: are there any other $P$ and $Q$ that satisfy equation $(1)$?